# How to bypass Microsoft .NET Framework Unhandled Exception?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My company recently started installing IO modules to production machines to capture data to our database. To do so we outsourced a 3rd party programmer to create an IO pulling software to draw data from IO module to a database in a collector PC.

The IO pulling software is running on the collector PC and will continue to draw data from machines into its local database for as long as the software is left open. No data will come in if the collector PC is shut down or the software is turned off.

The program works well but there was a bit of an oversight. If a machine gets unplugged or disconnected from the network (connection made via Ethernet cables), an unhandled exception error will appear for the pulling software for that particular machine.

[image]

Clearly its due to there being no connection and clicking Continue will solve this problem. But I'm afraid it will affect the quality of the data captured. Also our contract with the programmer who made this expired, so I'm the one who has to fix it.

The program was done in VB and I was thinking of just adding a procedure into the code to automatically bypass this error or at least tell the program to automatically select Continue and move on without human intervention. As I'm new to programming I'm not sure if my approach is even possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Never unplug a USB connector while a program is using it.  You **must** use the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon first.  Which always forces you to do the right thing.

Comment: The right way to handle this is to put in an exception handler in the right place to do the right thing when there is a connection problem (that is, wrap some specific code in a `Try`-`Catch` which catches a specific exception type).  Notwithstanding Hans's comment, it's conceivable you could have other connection problems, and they would also crash your program.

Comment: @Hans. The is no USB involved in this program. The IO module is connected to a PC with the pulling software via Ethernet cable. The program is always running safely within the PC.

Comment: I made some edits to the question to reflect on some recent clarifications.